# Preowned/Used Games for PS4

Tags: ps4

As much as the answer is known to be a "Yes", I want to understand the following:

1. Can I buy a preowned (used-very good/like new) game to use in PS4?
2. What should I not be expecting from a used/pre-owned PS4 game?

The question behind this is the Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare which I believe has gone down to an affordable range and I think I can buy one. But wasn't sure if I can actually play it normally?

Comment: About preowned game, only make sure about the DLC codes, if they are included but used, you can't use it again.

Answer (score 20):

As [DGarvanski has already covered](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243637/73976), there isn't any weird checking if you want to use pre-owned games on PS4. Like most pre-owned games however, *if* there was any additional content that was unlocked by the use of downloadable content, or passes or something similar, the likelihood of this still being available for a pre-owned game is unlikely, as they are only one-time use.

For future reference, Playstation have released an official guide for sharing/using pre-owned games on the Playstation 4 system:

Comment: Love the video, so detailed and thorough!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus This video is one of the reasons that Sony is winning the current console war.  Well, not this video itself, but what it represented.

Comment: Specifically, if highlighted the difference between how Sony and Microsoft were approaching this console generation.  MS was going to make a console that didn't allow used games and had a number of other dumb mistakes.  Sony capitalized upon these mistakes, and even though MS changed policies before launch, the PS4 came out with an early lead that it never lost.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, you can play it normally.**
The PS4 allows the use of pre-owned games without any online checks or weird DRM. I've checked and Call of Duty: AW has no "Online Pass" system in place so you wouldn't have to buy anything extra in order to play. The only thing that will be different is if you buy a special edition since you wouldn't have access to the DLC that comes with that edition unless you buy it separately . However, the PS4 will not have any problems with you playing a used copy.